# Sorting column names when they contain dates in MM-YYYY format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this below:

[image]

but as you can see the dates are sorted by the Month without the year

I need it to look like this below:

[image]

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: So if you provided data that people don't have to type in on your behalf you may get some doing some testing.

Comment: Convert column names to date time, sort the values, then convert back to the original format

Comment: No Images, post the data as a code preferably. Also, please review the guidelines in creating a MRE, expecting contributors to create the data manually to solve your question, is to too much of an expectation.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

col_names = df.keys()
col_in_datetime = [datetime.strptime(x, '%b-%y') for x in col_names]
sorted_in_datetime = sorted(col_in_datetime)
sorted_col_names = [x.strftime('%b-%y') for x in sorted_in_datetime]
df = df.reindex(sorted(sorted_col_names), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move name column to index,
Convert date column names to datetime and sort,
Convert date column names back to original format,
Move Name index back to column,

```
df = df.set_index("Name")
df.columns = [x.strftime("%b-%y") for x in sorted([pd.to_datetime(x, format="%b-%y", errors="coerce") for x in df.columns])]
df = df.reset_index()
```